# Netlogo How do I export the amount of increment counter number with turtle ID and ticks data?

Tags: export, counter, netlogo

How do I export the amount of increment counter number with turtle ID and ticks data? The following sample program is a part of an increment counter that activates the increment counter when the turtle speed reaches 0 and continues to operate until the turtle dies. The purpose is to take the waiting time of the turtle. 
Thank you for your cooperation best regards.

```
     ask turtles [ ;;counter for counting the waiting time
       if speed = 0 [
       set counter counter + 1 
       ]
       ]
```

Comment: Are you trying to export to file? If so, you could check out [the file in/out](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#fileio) section of the programming guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27527609/file-output-netlogo

Comment: Thank you for your advice to this. I am trying to refer the URL with this URL here, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690569/create-output-in-an-excel-file-consisting-of-data-rows  I will do my best for the adjustment a little more.